# Extending DataSource with a sub class in Spring Boot AutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm trying to write an auto-configuration library that adds functionality to any `DataSource`. I've written a sub-class that I'll call `CustomDataSource` here and which overrides some of the methods of `DataSource`.

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean(DataSource.class)
@AutoConfigureAfter(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class CustomDataSourceAutoConfiguration {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public CustomDataSourceAutoConfiguration(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public CustomDataSource customDataSource() {
        return new CustomDataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

But I can't find a way that allows me to do what I want. It will always result in a circular reference and the exception:

```
BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customDataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Huh, weird. Does it work if you use field injection for `dataSource` instead (`@Autowired private DataSource dataSource`)?

Comment: No, this results in the exact same error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to work around this issue by implementing a `BeanPostProcessor`:

```java
public class DataSourcePostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        if (bean instanceof DataSource && !(bean instanceof CustomDataSource)) {
            return new CustomDataSource((DataSource) bean);
        } else {
            return bean;
        }
    }

}
```

The `postProcessAfterInitialization` method can explicitly be used for wrapping beans in a proxy, citing from the [`BeanPostProcessor` documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html):

> [...] post-processors that wrap beans with proxies will normally implement `postProcessAfterInitialization(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)`.